# Laravel 10 hasManyThrough get all grandparent data with child's image

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables PhotoCategories, PhotoDetail, and Photo
Tables :
**PhotoCategories**

| PhotoCategories |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

**PhotoDetail**

| PhotoDetail |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| photo_categories_id |

**Photo**
| Photo          |
| ---------------|
| id             |
| image          |
| photo_detail_id|

Model :
**PhotoCategories**

```
class PhotoCategories extends Model
{

    public function photo_detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PhotoDetail::class);
    }

    public function photos() : HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Photo::class,
            PhotoDetail::class,
            'photo_detail_id',
            'photo_categories_id',
            'id',
            'id');
    }
}
```

**PhotoDetail**

```
class PhotoDetail extends Model
{
    public function photo_categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo(PhotoCategories::class, 'photo_categories_id');
    }

    public function photos() {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
    }
}
```

**Photo**

```
class Photo extends Model
{
    public function photo_detail() {
        return $this->belongsTo(PhotoDetail::class);
    }
}
```

I want to show all PhotoCategories's name with one Photo's image but I am confuse how to called the Model in Controller and Blade

I want to get all PhotoCategories's name with one Photo's image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have some mistakes, but anyhow I will give the query,
PhotoCategories model should be named as PhotoCategory and the table name as photo_categories.

now you can do something like this.

```
use App\Models\PhotoCategories;

public function index()
{
    $photoCategories = PhotoCategories::with('photos')->get();
    return view('view', compact('photoCategories'));
}
```

in your blade view you will itrate over the $photoCategories as like this.

```
@foreach($photoCategories as $category)
    <h2>{{ $category->name }}</h2>
    @if($category->photos->count() > 0)
        @foreach($category->photos as $photo)
            @if ($photo->image)
                <img src="{{ asset('public_folder_path/' . $photo->image) }}">
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>No photos available for this category.</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm still getting error from $category->photos->first()->image with error message "ErrorException Attempt to read property "image" on null"

Comment: it means that there are some categories without associated photos, and you are trying to access the image property on a null.
let me update the code